# How to merge 2 arrays of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm trying to do mi own serialize function (like in jQuery), I need to get inputs and selects in an array in order to serialize it.

The problem is that methods "push" and "pop" doesn't exist in DOM elements arrays (Error: "Undefined is not a function").

HTML:

```
     <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="age">Age:</label></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="age" name="age"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="genre">Genre:</label></td>
                <td><select name="genre" id="genre">
                    <option>Female</option>
                    <option>Male</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.ownSerialize=function() {

        var inputs = this.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var selects = this.getElementsByTagName('select');

        while(selects.length)inputs.push(selects.pop());//Breaks here
        console.log(inputs);

        var json = {};
        for (var f=0; f<inputs.length; f++) {
            json[inputs[f].id]=inputs[f].value;
        }
        console.log(json);

        var str = "?";
        for(f in json){
            str+=f+"="+json[f]+"&"
        }
        str = str.slice(0,-1); //Delete de last "&"
        console.log(str);
    };
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].ownSerialize();
```

How can I achieve it?
http://jsfiddle.net/mpecdv2t/

(Hope my english is correct)

Comment: I forget to write the button.
JsFiddle is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert HTMLCollection (and any other array-like collection) to native array with [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like) method:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
var inputs = slice.call(this.getElementsByTagName('input'));
var selects = slice.call(this.getElementsByTagName('select'));
```

After that `inputs` and `selects` are true javascript arrays with DOM elements as array elements.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mpecdv2t/1/